# GitHub Actions not finding cache

Tags: github, npm, caching, github-actions

I have a workflow which caches the output of:

- `composer install` using a hash of `composer.lock`
- `npm ci` using a hash of `package-lock.json`
- `npm run prod` using a hash of `public/**/*`

so they can be reused on subsequent runs.

The problem is, only the composer cache is ever hit - the two npm caches always result in a message in the CI output saying `Cache not found for input keys`.

Taking the `npm ci` code as an example, the cache setup and the subsequent usage are done by these two steps:

```yaml
- name: Cache node packages
  id: cache-npm-packages
  uses: actions/cache@v2
  env:
    cache-name: cache-node-packages
  with:
    # npm cache files are stored in `~/.npm` on Linux/macOS
    path: ~/.npm
    key: ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ hashFiles('package-lock.json') }}

- if: ${{ steps.cache-npm-packages.outputs.cache-hit != 'true' }}
  run: npm ci
```

But the CI output says:

```
Cache not found for input keys: Linux-build-cache-node-packages-4370b0e1b9396b576e8db83e048ce2efe36557c8c4bae8492253ef706fc8a4bc
```

Despite being in the list of cache entries:

[image: Image showing list of cache entries]

The screenshot also shows that the cache of `npm run prod` is repeatedly being generated and never reused.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using the `actions/cache@v3` instead of `v2`?

Answer (score 7):

I had this same issue, the problem is that a branch 'A' can only retrieve the cache of the 'main' branch or if it is a child branch.

> [image]

All your cache is being created by pull requests, as you can see `ref/pull/foo/merge`

Caches stored by pull request can only be accessed on re-runs on the same branch.

> [image]

To solve your problem, you should run the workflow once in the main branch, so any other action will be able to access it.

Comment: It's silly - doesn't make sense at all. People are complaining about this policy too: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/27059.